# Why I get: returning const char * from a function with result type char * discards qualifiers

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, char

I need te return an `NSString` as `char *`:

```
char *inboxPath (void) 
{ 
    NSURL * url = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                 URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
                 inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"inbox.txt"];
    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url] UTF8String]; 
}
```

I get: **Returning 'const char *' from a function with result type 'char *' discards qualifiers**

Why I get this and how I can solve it?
Obviously I don't know much C, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function:

```
char* inboxPath (void);
```

returns `char*` while `-[NSString UTF8String]` returns `const char*`. The qualifier you're dropping is the `const`. To solve this, you should declare your function:

```
const char* inboxPath (void);
```

Mutating immutable (`const`) data is one common way to introduce undefined behaviour, so you definitely want to avoid dropping the `const` qualifier.

If you need a mutable `char` buffer, make a copy of the utf8 string returned by `-[NSString UTF8String]`.

Comment: Note: “The returned C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you called this method.” – [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBHCCED)

Answer (score 3):

Add the qualifier to the returned value type in your function:

```
const char *inboxPath(...)
```

`UTF8String` returns a `const char *`, so you may want to return the same type in your function.